# Is there a way to regain preview workspace functionality in unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, workspaces

In unity the workspace switcher doesn't display active workspace number or a preview of workspaces like in previous versions. It's not comfortable to click on workspace switcher to look for a window and than double click to select it. I would like the workspace switcher to display more information. And i know of Indicator-Workspaces but it's not enough to regain all the lost functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible in 11.04.